# Binding List<struct> in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this constructor :

```
 public partial class MachinesWorkingTime : Window
 {
        public List<MachineWorkingTime> valuesMachine { get; set;}
        public MachinesWorkingTime(List<MachineWorkingTime> values)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            valuesMachine = values;
        }
 }
```

MachineWorkingTime struct :

```
public struct MachineWorkingTime
{
    public string machineName { get; set; }
    public List<string> posA;
}
```

This is my XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WorkingTimes.MachinesWorkingTime"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorkingTimes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MachinesWorkingTime" Height="178.243" Width="502.092">
<Grid Background="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding valuesMachine}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50" Width="50" Binding="{Binding machineName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

But I don't know why I cannot see anything in the datagrid.
Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in the output console, do you set the datacontext of the window?

Comment: @Chrille No errors. No, i try. Thanks!

Comment: Besides what's mentioned in the answer, don't use a struct (i.e. a value type) as collection element type. This will soon get you into unexpected trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext of the Window to your view model class. In your case the window class is used as a view model. Try this:

```
public MachinesWorkingTime(List<MachineWorkingTime> values)
{        
    valuesMachine = values;
    DataContext = this; //Set viewmodel of window to this
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I would recommend to split the view model from the Window class.

Also don't use a struct to hold your data when binding as Midfielder4 commented:

```
public class MachineWorkingTime
{
    public string machineName { get; set; }
    public List<string> posA;
}
```